# pyqgis standalone applicaton windows

Tags: pyqgis

Ive downloaded QGIS 3.22
according to documentation, I need to set PYTHONPANTH and PATH to make pyqgis visible from python for a stand alone application:

set PYTHONPATH=c:<qgispath>\python

such folder doesnt exist. Specificly c:\program files\qgis 3.22\python

I set the path to many folders in the directory (\apps\qgis\bin, apps\qgis\python\qgis....) but it doesnt work.

Im checking the sys.path and the new PYTHONPATH is there.
still when importing qgis.core , i get "no module qgis"

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for [Running Custom Applications](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications). Make sure you have the DLL and lib folders in your PYTHONPATH. Check the environment variables using the built-in interpreter (the order of directories in PATH matters) and make sure they match your standalone environment. Also, your install should come with a `python-qgis-ltr.bat` or `python-qgis.bat` bootstrap file which is a nice starting point for setting up your own environment (on windows).